# mysql Unknown column 'T.subscription_package_id' in 'on clause'

Tags: mysql

Please check following query it will give me error  MySQL said: Documentation
 - 
`Unknown column 'T.subscription_package_id' in 'on clause'`

```
SELECT COALESCE(T.SUBSCRIPTION_STATUS, 'N') as SUBSCRIPTION_STATUS, c.assigned_executive as user_id,concat(ud.first_name,' ',ud.last_name) as username,c.id as customer_id, concat(c.first_name,' ',c.last_name) as customer_name ,c.mobile 
    FROM tbl_customer c 
    LEFT join tbl_user_details ud on c.assigned_executive=ud.user_id 
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT a1.customer_id, (CASE WHEN a1.available_credits > 0 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) AS SUBSCRIPTION_STATUS FROM tbl_customer_subscription a1 GROUP BY a1.customer_id)T ON c.id = T.customer_id 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_subscription_package_services z ON z.subscription_package_id = T.subscription_package_id 
    group by c.id
```

Comment: The only thing evident from your above query is that your table `tbl_customer_subscription` doesn't contain the column `subscription_package_id`. Rest can only be discussed if you share the output of `create table` or `desc` statement.

Comment: When you do a `LEFT JOIN` with a subquery, your subquery has to include all of the fields you want to reference. The `T` alias, does not have the column `subscription_package_id` referenced. That is why you receive the `Unknown column` error.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is because you are trying to get a field from a SUBQUERY and that subquery doesn't have the desired field:

```
(SELECT a1.customer_id, 
       (CASE WHEN a1.available_credits > 0 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) AS SUBSCRIPTION_STATUS 
   FROM tbl_customer_subscription a1 
  GROUP BY a1.customer_id) T
```

And this subquery doesn't have the field you are trying to fetch. When you use a subquery as a table only the fields selected are available to use, not the union of the selected plus the table which seems you think it would work, so add your field on the subquery

```
(SELECT a1.customer_id,
        a1.subscription_package_id, -- here the missing field
       (CASE WHEN a1.available_credits > 0 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) AS SUBSCRIPTION_STATUS 
   FROM tbl_customer_subscription a1 
  GROUP BY a1.customer_id) T
```

So when you do `ON z.subscription_package_id = T.subscription_package_id` it will work because it is now present.

Comment: need to join tbl_subscription_package_services with tbl_customer_subscription "subscription_package_id" available in both table

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand. Can you edit your question adding the tables structure please?